# Pyramid of pin using Recursion

Tags: java

[image]I want to print a pyramid of pins using recursion(no Loops). I got the code almost done, but my pyramid is upside down, and it is not formatted. How can I fix it.
Below is my source code:

```
public void pinPattern(int count) {
        if(count == 1)
            System.out.println("*");
        else {
            System.out.print("*");
            pinPattern(count - 1);
        }
    }

    public int numberOfPins(int n) {
        if(n == 0)
            return 0;
        else {
            pinPattern(n);
            return n + numberOfPins(n - 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Recursion x = new Recursion();
        System.out.println("The number of pin: " + x.numberOfPins(5));
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I added my current output as a png file. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

So there are two considerations here. First, the need to have the pyramid go the other direction. If it is printing upside-down, then instead of counting down (which goes from max to min), invert the approach. Something like:

```
public static int pinPatternUp(int numPins, int maxPins)
{
    if (numPins <= maxPins) {
        // this will add spaces
        spaces(maxPins - numPins);
        pins(numPins);
        return numPins + (pinPattern(numPins + 1, maxPins));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The logic for the `pins` method (which in the OP's code was 'pinPattern`) in the OP's approach is essentially fine for either direction. However, making this change (so that there is a space after each`*`) will allow for a bit better formatting.

```
System.out.print("* ");
```

The second question is one of formatting. In this case, we can look at the pyramid as requiring *N* spaces before the first output. And with a bit of investigation, it appears that a given line will have the total number of rows - the current row in terms of spaces. Using recursion, it is possible to do something like:

```
public static void spaces(int num)
{
    if (num == 0) {
        return;
    }
    System.out.print(" ");
    spaces(num - 1);
}
```

Note that one can now have an "up" or "down" facing pyramid depending upon whether the `pinPattern` is increasing or decreasing.

Note: due to some editing, the method names do not exactly align with the OP's.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    pinPatternUp(1, 5);
    pinPatternDown(5, 5);
}
```

Output if run up and then down:

```
    *
   * *
  * * *
 * * * *
* * * * *
* * * * *
 * * * *
  * * *
   * *
    *
```